# Passing parameters on a batch file

Tags: windows, file, scripting, batch-file

Could anyone help me out, I have a batch file find.bat

which has a statement:

findmp %VARIABLE%

what I would like to find out is how to pass a paramater on the batch file

e.g. find.bat /C:\Test

So when called the batch file would execute:

findmp C:\Test

Can this be done in Batch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can't be the first parameter?

```
find.bat c:\test
```

and inside the bat:

```
findmp "%1"
```

Comment: if the name have spaces remember to wrap in "" when calling `find.bat "C:\test dir\other"`

Comment: That is worth being incorporated into the answer. Also `"%1"` should be either `%1` or `"%~1"`.